# UICollectionView Layout Wrong Item Size

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I am programmatically creating a `UICollectionViewController`:

```
class MyCollectionVC: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {


init() {
        super.init(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())    
}


override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()

    self.collectionView.delegate = self

    ...
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout:
    UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let dimension = self.view.bounds/3
    return CGSize(width: dimension, height: dimension)

}

override final func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

 print ("Cell Size: (self.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout).itemSize)

}
```

}

I need thee actually cell size at `cellForItemAt` to do more work.

Cell size above prints out 50 x 50 at all times. This is the default size given. iPhone or iPad, portrait of landscape, it is always 50.

The odd thing is, the actual cell layout gets displayed correctly. Everything else works and looks perfectly.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Define "more work". Shouldn't more work done inside the cell, which might change its alyout according to its size, not according to the current size in `collectionView(_:cellForItem:)`? Just check, which on is called before/after: the `sizeForItemAt` or `cellForItemAt`? Shouldn't `cellForItemAt` just handle some "logic", but not necessary all UI one?

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
class GridLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.minimumLineSpacing = 0
        self.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func prepare() {
        super.prepare()
        guard let collectionView = self.collectionView else {return}
        let cellWidth = collectionView.frame.width / 3
        self.itemSize = CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: cellWidth) // Your Cell Size
    }
}
```

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = GridLayout()
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
    }
```

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
 
        print((self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout).itemSize)
        
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Your Cell Id", for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }
```